# Tips for flirting with NPC

Tags: roleplaying, npc, romance

I play a character that's currently in love with an NPC, but it's not working. I wanted some hints about what to do, and what to say (gestures, actions, etc.) to make him fall for me. Apparently he trusts me, but we can't even say that we're friends, since there's no conversation. The GM doesn't cooperate since he won't talk back, leaving everything for me to do. So, what should I say on those times when we're alone? Basically, I need some catch-up phrases or something like that, that would help a lot. I don't want to leave everything 100% up to dice rolling since I'm afraid of rolling too low and then having no chance whatsoever. By the way, I received kind of an "ultimatum" because I talk a lot about their relationship both in game and outside of it. The GM said that if I kept this up he would feel intimidated, but MY CHARACTER AND THE NPC BARELY TALK. Please Help!

Comment: This seems like an idea generation question. As currently phrased, it seems a little too broad for a Q&A site like RPG.SE. It's also heavily dependent on your DM's cooperation.

Comment: What is the end goal for the love interest Between your character and the NPC?

Comment: I think there's an answerable question here around "By the way, I received kind of an "ultimatum" because I talk a lot about their relationship (in game and outside of it), the GM said that if i keep up he would feel intimidated but MY CHARACTER AND THE NPC BARELY TALK." If you can [edit] to focus on resolving this, RPG SE might be able to help you, or another SE site.

Comment: @Thatguy While editing grammar and spelling is important, you may want to wait to do so until after the first edit (perhaps the clarifying edit from the OP) since only the first edit automatically puts it on the list of questions eligible for reopening. Since it has already been edited, someone will have to manually add it to the list by revoting if it ends up being adjusted to fit in with the stack.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with a difference in how you and the DM are handling this; asking for acting tips kinda skips past the problem, right? Asking about that first problem itself would help focus this.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but it sounds a lot like you're obsessing over a relationship with a NPC and it's making your DM uncomfortable. This would be a better fit for the interpersonal stackexchange.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, how to set up a game to allow/encourage for pc/npc flirtations?

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen PCs attempt to seduce NPCs, it always goes like this:

> PC: "I'd like to romance this NPC."
>   DM: "Okay, roll Persuasion."

You've noted that you don't want to leave it up to the dice, but unfortunately that's not how this normally works.  It's possible you could get your DM to improvise a "win this NPC's love" quest for you, but your DM might not want to make the story about that.

---

The problem with romance plots in RPGs is that they leave most of the players with nothing to do.  It might be pretty fun to roleplay romancing an NPC, but it's sure not fun to sit there for twenty minutes listening to someone else roleplay romancing an NPC.  Consider that the DM probably wants to make sure all the players have fun, and that might be why the DM is trying to discourage you from pursuing this plotline.